# Msi: Can dword values in Registry Table expressed in hexadecimal number?

Tags: scripting, installation, wix, windows-installer

Preceding registry value data by a number-sign (`#`) causes the value interpreted as a dword in decimal number. This is OK and I have no problem with it. I'm just curious, is there a way to express it in a hexadecimal number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently not.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The "#x" prefix understands hex but produces a REG_BINARY value instead of a REG_DWORD.